# Remove the row with ID equals zero for all the ID's having values greater than zero.

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this

```
ID <- c("A","A","A","B","B","C","D")
Value <- c(0,1,2,0,2,0,0)
df <- data.frame(ID,Value)
df
```

I am trying to apply the logic that if any ID has values greater than 0, then I need to remove that row of the ID with 0.

**My desired output is**

```
  ID Value
   A     1
   A     2
   B     2
   C     0
   D     0
```

I tried doing it this way

```
df <- subset(df,df$Value !=0)
```

I know this is wrong since it removes any ID with 0. Please help with some inputs on how to solve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vanilla way:

```
# get ids with values greater than 0
delete_zero = unique(subset(df, Value > 0)$ID)

# delete the rows where the ID is in delete_zero AND the value is 0
df2 = subset(df, !(ID %in% delete_zero & Value == 0))

df2
#   ID Value
# 2  A     1
# 3  A     2
# 5  B     2
# 6  C     0
# 7  D     0
```

The newfangled way: same logic but we do it with `dplyr` "by group"

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(ID) %>%
    filter(!(any(Value > 0) & Value == 0))

# Source: local data frame [5 x 2]
# Groups: ID [4]
# 
#       ID Value
#   <fctr> <dbl>
# 1      A     1
# 2      A     2
# 3      B     2
# 4      C     0
# 5      D     0
```

Comment: Or invert the logic with `all` and `|`: `df %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(all(Value == 0) | Value > 0)`

Answer (score 3):

You could use `ave()`, first coercing the `Value` column to logical so that out result will be a vector use for subsetting.  We use an `if()` statement to determine the values to keep.

```
df[with(df, ave(as.logical(Value), ID, FUN = function(x) if(any(x)) x else !x)), ]
#   ID Value
# 2  A     1
# 3  A     2
# 5  B     2
# 6  C     0
# 7  D     0
```

Or the same with `subset()`.

```
subset(df, ave(as.logical(Value), ID, FUN = function(x) if(any(x)) x else !x))
#   ID Value
# 2  A     1
# 3  A     2
# 5  B     2
# 6  C     0
# 7  D     0
```

Answer (score 2):

A `dplyr` approach:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(if (all(Value==0)) TRUE else Value > 0)
Source: local data frame [5 x 2]
Groups: ID [4]

      ID Value
  <fctr> <dbl>
1      A     1
2      A     2
3      B     2
4      C     0
5      D     0
```